# Looking for a formula to return a result of valid or invalid if two dependant cells compare to an original cell

Tags: excel

I would like to compare the values of three cells and return "Valid" or "Invalid":

```
A1 can only have the responses      0,1+,2+,3+, or 4+.  
B1 can have the same responses      0,1+,2+,3+, or 4+.   
C1 can also have only the responses 0,1+,2+,3+, or 4+.
```

Cells `B1` and `C1` are dependent on `A1`. By that statement I mean that if cell `A1` has a     response of 0 then `B1` and `C1` should have the same response of 0 to be "Valid" If not i.e.

```
A1=0, B1=1+, and C1=0 or A1=0, B1=0, and C1=1+
```

then in either scenario `B1` or `C1` do not compare to `A1` being 0 and the argument is "Invalid".

Now for the confusing part if `A1` has a value of 1+ or 2+ or 3+ or 4+ then either `B1` or `C1` must have a value of 1+ or 2+ or 3+ or 4+ to be valid. What I am trying to accomplish is:

```
A1    B1    C1   Argument is   
 0     0     0    "Valid" as B1 and C1 both have a response of 0  
 0    1+     0    "Invalid" as both B1 and C1 are not 0 as is A1
 0     0    1+    "Invalid" as both B1 and C1 are not 0 as is A1
2+    1+     0    "Valid" as either B1 or C1 had a 1+,2+,3+, or 4+ 
                     when compared to A1 having a 1+,2+,3+ or 4+ response. 
3+    1+    2+    "Valid" as both B1 or C1 had a 1+,2+,3+ or 4+ response.   
                     when compared to A1 having a 1+,2+,3+ or 4+ response. 
3+     0    4+    "Valid' as either B1 or C1 had a 1+,2+,3+ or 4+ response  
                     when compared to A1 having a 1+,2+,3= or 4+ response.     
4+     0     0    "Invalid" as neither B1 or C1 had a 1+, or 2+ or 3+ or 4+
                     response in comparison to A1
```

I do not know if a formula can be configured in Excel 2010 (WS) for the responses of "Valid" or "Invalid" or if the only way to get a "Valid" or "Invalid" response would be to setup through VBA. I have never used VBA.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use Data Validation: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HP010072600.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

`=IF(COUNTA(A1,B1,C1)=3,IF(OR(AND(A1=0,OR(B1<>0,C1<>0)),AND(A1<>0,B1=0,C1=0)),"Invalid","Valid"),"")`

You get a blank result unless all three cells are populated.

If they **are** populated you only get `invalid` if A1 is zero and either of the others is not....or if A1 is not zero but both B1 and C1 are zero, otherwise `valid`